# Problema de concurrencia y consulta BD

Tags: mysql, jsf

Estoy teniendo un problema en mi proyecto que es java web con JSF y Mysql que es lo siguiente:

- Tengo una tabla en mysql llamada consecutivos que es consultada por los usuarios para consultar un registro que es correspondiente a su empresa y éste mismo registro se actualiza una vez consumido el consecutivo sumandole un uno.

Ej: el usuario de la empresa 1 consulto el registro de la tabla consecutivos que estaba en 6 e inmediatamente quedo en 7 para que otro usuario de la misma empresa venga y consulte ese consecutivo.

- El problema es cuando dos usuarios de la misma empresa consulta a tabla consecutivos casi o al mismo tiempo, en el tiempo en que la consultan ésta devuelve el mismo numero a los dos usuarios,pero se actualiza sumandole dos.

Ej: El usuario 1 y el usuario 2 (que son de la misma empresa) consultan la tabla al mismo tiempo y el registro de su empresa está en 6, pero cuando la consulta los dos al mismo tiempo ésta devuelve ese 6 a los dos usuarios en vez de devolver 6 a uno y 7 al otro y quedar en 8 el registro.

Alguna solución a éste problema? He estado viendo colas, pero no se muy bien como implementarlas.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu código (solamente SQL) para consultar y actualizar? Se hacen las dos operaciones al mismo tiempo o en dos momentos diferentes?

Comment: Las operaciones se hacen en dos momentos diferentes, tengo dos procedimientos almacenados para cada una, lo usaria con un trigger, pero no se me permite hacerlo

Comment: En la práctica es muy poco probable que dos usuarios hagan la misma consulta exactamente al mismo tiempo, por lo que primero podrías actualizar el campo que te interesa (lo cual lo incrementaría en 1), luego le presentas los resultados de la consulta al usuario pero restandole 1 (en la presentación, no en la base de datos). Así siempre verían el registro actualizado al número anterior a que ellos se conectaran.